# Android request Location Permission Dialog doesn't show up third time after don't allow

Tags: android, kotlin, location, android-permissions, android-location

I have this simple activity which popups the location permission dialog and based on negative or positive permission dialog button interaction I clear the activity.As a user when I dismiss the dialog for the second time and come back to the app again the dialog doesn't show up anymore and the activity just finishes right away. I would want to show the permission dialog every-time if the permission was not granted

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    setupPermission()
  }

  private fun setupPermission() {
    val permission = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      permissionsResultCallback.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    } else {
      Log.d("dawg", "already granted")
      finish()
    }
  }

  private val permissionsResultCallback = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
    when (granted) {
      true -> {
        Log.d("dawg", "granted now via dialog")
        finish()
      }
      false -> {
        Log.d("dawg", "denied via dialog")
        finish()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's a feature of Android itself and as far as I know you can't bypass that (and you shouldn't!). It protects the user from being spammed by the same permission request all the time

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)). If the user deny for 2nd time you can show a snack bar where user can goto settings page and turn on notification manually.

```
if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                      
                            showSnackBarForOpenSettings(
                                context,
                                "Camera  Permission needed",
                                view
                            )
                       }
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            requireActivity(),
                            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 1
                        )
                    }
```

For opening app settings screen you can use this:

```
fun Context.openAppSystemSettings() {
        startActivity(Intent().apply {
            action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
        })
    }
```

use it like this  `context.openAppSystemSettings()`

Comment: isn't that just pain for the user and developer!!